# Black screen in chrome after sleep

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, electron, chromium

I'm experiencing black screen in google chrome (and a lot more...read below) after waking windows 10 up from sleep mode.

This issue appears in **google chrome** and **all derived applications**, in few words I'm experiencing this in:

1. Google chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (pretty sure i was having this issue also before)
2. The new Microsoft Edge browser based on chromium
3. All the pwa (progressive web apps) installed with chrome or edge

**All electron applications** like:

4. Visual Studio Code
5. Whatsapp
6. All the Electron applications made by me.

I had this issue for a long time but the spreading of chrome based services is going to make this thing a lot annoying...

I'm using Windows 10 1909 home 64 bit (pretty sure I was having this issue also in windows 10 1903)

WORKAROUND: if in google chrome (or edge chromium) i keep a tab that in the closing prompts a javascript alert, in the moment when the alert is prompted, the issue is gone, the black screen is gone and i can return to see the whole tabs.
So after waking up windows 10 from sleep mode, if i see black screen in the browser i can just close it with the cross in the top right corner, in that moment the alert is prompted "are you sure to leave this page?", i answer "no i want to stay in this page" and the issue is gone. 
Of course this is a workaround cause you can forget to keep that site in the tabs of chrome/edge, and this doesn't resolve the issue in visual studio code.

Comment: You should enable logging in Chrome and checkout the log file after this issue replicates. There could be so many reasons behind this issue.

Comment: I replicated the issue in chrome with the log enabled.
In the end of the log file i can see tons of messages like this:
"[5996:1320:0411/223937.096:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(561)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed"

Honestly i don't know how to interpret this...

Comment: Look for other error messages too. Those are common error message which most likely isn't the reason behind your issue.

Comment: i see this exact issue in Chrome 85 under Linux after updating to the latest NVIDIA drivers.  I thought that might be it, bu the fact that it only happens with Chrome AND somebody has reported it under Windows makes me suspect maybe not

Answer (score 1):

Starting google-chrome with the `--use-gl=desktop` seems to work with no side effects.

I had same issue with Fedora, Chrome and NVIDA drivers. At first I tried enbling the vulkan flag.

Go to [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags) and enable `ignore-gpu-blacklist` and `enable-vulkan`. However, Chrome performance suffers and others have pointed out with this settings.

Found the vulkan tip in a comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272864/20-04-google-chrome-display-glitches-after-wake-up). The use-gl-desktop tip [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274056/647059)

Comment: #enable-vulkan does indeed fix it, but introduces other issues like very bad performance when for example a video is played in the browser - so it's not really a solution, at least for me.

Comment: yes, indeed I don't have anymore this issue.
now on windows 10 2004, chrome 85.0.4183.121, and 456.55 nvidia drivers.